# Is there a way to input a unicode value and output its respective char?

Tags: java, loops, unicode

I have here some code trying to output seat numbers. The output is formatted as such for `numRows = 2` and `numCols = 3: 1A 1B 1C 2A 2B 2C`

My problem below is with my `char.forDigit` method. What I am trying to do is input Unicode values (65 being A, 66 being B, etc) and output their respective chars.  Any help?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++){
     for (int j = 1; j <= numCols; j++){
        System.out.print(i + char.forDigit(65 + j) + " ");
     }
  }
```

Comment: `char` is a primitive type, it doesn't have methods.

Comment: lol... my bad .. jesus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.print(i +""+ ((char)(65 + j)) + " ");
```

Explicit Type Conversion or type casting.

Comment: Is this a basic concept in java?

Comment: how did you guys learn java? Because evidently what I'm doing is useless

Comment: you have to put  `(i + "" + ((char)...`

Comment: @David how did I learn? Well I'm still 16 and started coding about an year ago so there's a lot of stuff which I'm yet to learn .. As of now i refer The complete Reference Java by Herbert Schildt..

Comment: I use The complete Reference , java api docs , tutorialspoint.com and tutorials.jenkov

Answer (score 2):

`char` is a primitive type, and you cannot invoke methods on a primitive type. However, it is also an integral type (which means you can perform arithmetic). You could do something like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%d%c ", 1 + i, 'A' + j);
    }
    System.out.println(); // <-- Don't forget to create a newline for the next row
}
```

**Additionally**, based on your stated objective *what I am trying to do is input Unicode values (65 being A, 66 being B, etc) and output their respective chars*; I would use a basic cast like

```
int c = 65;
System.out.println((char) c);
```

***or***, `printf` again like

```
int c = 65;
System.out.printf("%c", c);
```

Both of which output (the requested)

```
A
```

Comment: hey, what's the best way you know of to learn java?  Because I never learned about explicit casting  which seems quite off

Comment: The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5) is the free, online and covers casting (see the link). There are many good [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) as well.